# Is there a way to run two different commands/instructions on two different bash terminals simultaneously?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

Here is a sample example -

***Terminal1***

```
$ ./file_name1.sh
```

***Terminal2***

```
$ ./file_name2.sh
```

More specifically what I want is, to print `stdout` on one terminal & `stderr` on another terminal simultaneously from a program.

Can it be done using a terminal like `terminator` or any other?

Answer (score 5):

Terminals are exposed as devices. If you have terminal 1 on `/dev/tty/1` and terminal 2 on `/dev/tty/2` you can run

```
 ./file_name_1.sh >/dev/tty/1 2>/dev/tty/2
```

to have its standard output displayed in terminal 1 and standard output in terminal 2. Of course, if you have anything else, like an interactive shell, in one of those terminals, you are making a mess for yourself. Probably a better solution would be to log to a file, and run `tail` on the file(s) you want to look at in each terminal as you see fit.

```
./file_name_1.sh >stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

then in terminal 1

```
tail -f stdout.log
```

and in terminal 2

```
tail -f stderr.log
```

The `tty` command can be used interactively to display information about the current terminal; on most platforms, you can also see terminal information in `ps` output, but what options exactly to use depends on which OS you are on. On Linux generally, try `ps a` for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some pair of named pipes and redirect stdout and stderr to these pipes.
On whatever terminal you like, you could then read from these pipes.

```
mkfifo mystdout  
mkfifo mystderr

./program >mystdout 2>mystderr
```

on terminal 1:

`tail -f mystdout`

on terminal 2:

`tail -f mystderr`